# Using NetworkX to position Nodes on PyQt QgraphicsScene

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, qt4, pyqt4, networkx

Hello I have been looking at graph libraries that will allow me to create interactive graphs on PyQt QgraphicsScene,(kind of like facebook/LinkedIn social graphs) while I have not found many python libraries that work well with Qt/PyQt(fast, with numerous layout algorithms) 
At first I thought I would use Boost Graph Library(BGL), see SO question titled **"Using Boost Graph Library in Python"**
I have now done some experiments with NetworkX, using NetworkX i can make a graph with a suitable layout(spring_layout is my current favourite). See code below

```
def draw_nx_graph(self):
    graph = [(20, 21),(21, 22),(22, 23), (23, 24),(24, 25), (25, 20),(2, 3),(3, 4),(12, 13)]
    # extract nodes from graph
    nodes = set([n1 for n1, n2 in graph] + [n2 for n1, n2 in graph])

    # create networkx graph
    G=networkx.Graph()#  nx.Graph()

    # add nodes
    for node in nodes:
        G.add_node(node)

    # add edges
    for edge in graph:
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

    # draw graph
    #pos = networkx.spectral_layout(G)
    pos = networkx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)
    networkx.draw(G, pos)

    for n in G.nodes():
        print type(n)


    # show graph
    plt.show()
```

Now the pos object gives a dictionary of positions keyed by node, the image below
  [image: Screenshot of Pos] 
shows the positions of each of the nodes. 
I would like to know how best to transform these positions(ndarrays) to QPointF so that I can place the nodes on a QGraphicsScene.

Each position being so close together has made me a little worried that if I just create QPointF with exactly the same values as the shown in the pos dictionary all the nodes will be clumped together,Is there a way to map these positions to a QGraphicsScene so nodes are laid out as per the alogrithm and also nicely spaced out over the area of the QGraphicsScene?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes are spaced inside [0, 1] × [0, 1] by default. You can change this coordinate range using the scale keyword argument to fruchterman_reingold_layout, or you can simply scale + offset the coordinates to a given bounding box in your graphics scene.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Just to add on to the answer, here is the code I implemented,

```
def generate_graph_and_update_scene(self):

    try:
        local_params=locals() #for error log  get local paramters
        this_function_name=sys._getframe().f_code.co_name #for error log  get function name


        self.vertex_dict.clear()
        self.clear() #clear graphicsscene

        self.graph_pos.clear() #clear graph position holder object

        #function that generates the node data
        root_nodes=my_database_query.get_nodes_information()
        for node in root_nodes:
            # add nodes to nx.graph object
            self.nx_graph.add_node(node['column1'])


        # create networkx graph
        self.graph_pos = nx.spring_layout(self.nx_graph, iterations=25,scale=10)

        for node in self.nx_graph.nodes(): # Add nodes to qgraphicsscene

            v=default_nodeobject.my_ellipse(node,self.graph_pos)               
            self.addItem(v) # Add ellipse to qgraphics scene

        for edge in self.nx_graph.edges():
            self.addItem(defaultedgeview.edgeview(edge[0], edge[1],self.graph_pos))#add edges to qgraphicscene

    except:
        #Exception handler
        message=str(sys.exc_info())
        message=message + str(local_params)+" "+ str(this_function_name)
        print message
```

The scale really helped, though I must confess that when adding lots of nodes 1500+   nx.spring_layout(self.nx_graph, iterations=25,scale=10)
is for some reason noticeable slow, but generally that what I ended up doing